# Unable to show alert dialog in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I working on sample code given [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/6/21/Update-to-my-ServerBased-Login-PhoneGap-Demo)...

I'm using Android SDK 4.0.3
cordova-2.7.0.js
jquery-1.9.0.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
auth.js

I'm trying to show login failed and login sucess alert dialog, but its not working.. Please tell me where i'm doing mistake...

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.phonegaplogintest;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    // @Override
    // protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/main.html");
        this.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
        this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new Console(), "console");
    }

    public  class Console {
          public  static  final  String TAG =  "Gap login test" ;
          public  void log ( String msg ) {
            Log.d(TAG, msg) ;
          }
        }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GISPLUS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"></link>

<!-- <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="auth.js"></script>


<!-- User-generated css -->
<style>
</style>
<!-- User-generated js -->

</head>

<body onload="init()">

    <div id="launcherPage" data-role="page">
        <!-- I'm just here waiting for deviceReady -->
    </div>

    <div id="loginPage" data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Auth Demo</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <form id="loginForm">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
                        name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                        name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>  

<!--    <script>
    $("#loginPage").live("pageinit", function(e) {
       checkPreAuth();
    });
</script> -->

</body>

</html>
```

main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./index.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

auth.js

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);
    delete init;
}

function checkPreAuth() {
    console.log("checkPreAuth");
    var form = $("#loginForm");
    if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password"] != undefined) {
        $("#username", form).val(window.localStorage["username"]);
        $("#password", form).val(window.localStorage["password"]);
        handleLogin();
    }
}

function handleLogin() {
    var form = $("#loginForm");    
    //disable the button so we can't resubmit while we wait
    $("#submitButton",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
    var u = $("#username", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val();
    if(u != '' && p!= '') {
        console.log("Submiting into URL...");

        $.post("http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/2011/nov/10/service.cfc?method=login&returnformat=json", {username:u,password:p}, function(res) {
            if(res == true) {
                console.log("Login Success.");
                //store
                window.localStorage["username"] = u;
                window.localStorage["password"] = p;             
                $.mobile.changePage("some.html");
            } else {
                console.log("Login Failed.");
                navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});
            }
         $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        },"json");
    } else {
        console.log("Please enter u & p");
        navigator.notification.alert("You must enter a username and password", alertDismissed, 'Login Failed!', 'OK' });
        $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    return false;
}

function deviceReady() {
    console.log("deviceReady");
    $("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
        console.log("pageinit run");
        $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
        checkPreAuth();
    });
    $.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
}

function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

notification.alert("Your login failed"); instd of

navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});